# Ember - Getting the model id out of a route and post to server

Tags: javascript, post, ember.js, ember-data

I am adding commenting to my ember app. When I submit a comment I want to add the object id of the current model as a foreign key to the comment object.

My html:

```
<div id="respond">
<h3>Leave a Comment</h3>
<form {{action leaveComment on="submit"}} class="form-inline">
    <h5>Your Name:</h5>
    {{input type="text" value=myname}}<br>
    <h5>Your Email:</h5>
    {{input type="text" value=myemail}}<br>
    <h5>Comment:</h5>
    {{textarea class="form-control" rows="3" type="text" value=mycomment}}<br>
    <h5>Tool Id:</h5>
    {{input type="text" value=id}}<br>      
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button-form">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
```

When I use this code, on the site my last input box contains the id of the active model (which is what I want) but when I post it, it is left blank. It is the only field that does not work.

Here is my js:

```
App.ViewController = Ember.Controller.extend({
name: null,
email: null,
comment: null,
toolid: null,
leaveComment: function() {
  var comment = App.Comment.createRecord({
    name: this.get('myname'),
    email: this.get('myemail'),
    comment: this.get('mycomment'),
    toolid: this.get('id')
  });

  comment.save().then(function() {
    this.transitionToRoute('view');
    this.set('myname', '');
    this.set('myemail', '');
    this.set('mycomment', '');
    this.set('id', '');
  }.bind(this));
}
});
```

### NOTE: Everything else posts fine.

EDIT: MODELS ADD on Request

```
App.Tool = DS.Model.extend({
  expertise: DS.attr('string'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  link: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  rating: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  comment: DS.attr('string'),
  toolid: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: Can you add your models pls

Comment: how its `toolid` defined in your model?

Comment: I've even used only the working set of attributes and then swapped one out for the id. It had the same effect. (It shows up on the page as expected but then posts as an empty string)

Comment: Important to note: the same effect occurs when I try to use any other attribute of the active model. In this case a tool listing.

Comment: so what do you see if you log something like `comment.getProperties('id', 'name')` after calling `App.Comment.createRecord`? also, can you try reproduce in a jsbin?

Comment: just a few things I noticed: would make the controller a object controller, put the action in the "actions" section, try to access the id of the tool with `this.get('model.id')`, your are defining controller variables but not using them, e.g. email. I agree, a jsbin would help

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. It is a little hard to tell without seeing your routes.

1: If the model is associated with this controller, try this.get('model').get('id');

2: Access the model through a parent controller, i.e.

```
App.CommentController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['tool']
});
```

Then you can access the tool id via this.get('controllers.tool').get('model').

Note that this is dependent on your routes being nested.